# Why didn't I gained rep for the last suggested edits

Tags: support, suggested-edits

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3755692/msrd0?tab=reputation&sort=post) on my profile site, it seems like I did not gain any rep for the last 5 approved suggested edits I made ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5941823)). Why didn't I get 2 rep for them?

Comment: could it be you hit the 200 rep a day limit?

Comment: Perhaps because you've already received 1,000 reputation points from previous accepted suggested edits?

Comment: @Julldar I don't think I hit the rep limit today ...

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce I didn't count, but does such a limit exist?

Comment: @msrd0 easy way to count : you have the copy editor badge. So you have 500 approved edits, 500 * 2 = 1000. you hit that limit :)

Comment: Yes. Up to 1000 reputation points or until you reach 2000 reputation, whichever comes first. Let me see if I can dig it up.

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce [This data query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/218899/my-accepted-edits) says that I only did 555 aproved suggested edits (nice number :))

Comment: do the maths. 555 * 2 = 1110 which is more than 1000 ;) Also, that's definitely not "only". Thank you for contributing to site-quality, please keep doing so ;)

Comment: Go to [stackoverflow.com/reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation).  Scroll to the end.  Very last line will read something like "earned 512 reputation from suggested edits"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you've already gained 1000 reputation from having your suggested edits accepted.

From the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation):

> You gain reputation when:
>
> - question is voted up: +5
> - answer is voted up: +10
> - answer is marked “accepted”: +15 (+2 to acceptor)
> - suggested edit is accepted: +2 **(up to +1000 total per user)**
> - bounty awarded to your answer: +full bounty amount
> - one of your answers is awarded a bounty automatically: +1/2 of the bounty amount (see more
>     details about how bounties work)
> - site association bonus: +100 on each site (awarded a maximum of one time per site)

*Emphasis mine.*